# WCF service singleton with callback and hosted on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, callback, singleton

I have a WCF service hosted at IIS7 web application. It's created by a WebServiceHostFactory. The client connects to a service calls the Collect method, and data are stored to DB. All working fine.

Now I would like to refresh page every time the new data are "collected" (i.e. the service method Collect is called).

My question is: What is the best approach ?

I was considering the CallbackContract, but this would require a singleton pattern (service is now PerCall), or is it a wrong assumption ? Is this approach possible ?

My logic is:

1. ASP.NET page subscribes to WCF service
2. the service singleton is created from now on
3. when method is called the services calls subscribers (clients)
4. there should be therefore only one service instance in order to subscription to work (or is it ?)
5. the client page refreshes itself

regards,
Kate

Comment: How do you plan to trigger the page reload of the ASP.NET page in the browser? Unless you use some advanced push products you'll have to poll the ASP.NET page which can in turn poll your WCF service.

Comment: Yep, I was concentrating on solving the callback problem I missed the obvious. It was about page updates without user interaction. So timer it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refresh the page in a user's browser from the sever. Browsers use HTTP, which is a request-response protocol, so if the browser hasn't issued a request, it won't be looking for a response from your server.

If you have a Silverlight application hosted in a browser, that's a different story, but you didn't mention Silverlight anywhere. You would also be able to do what you're asking using WebSockets in HTML5, but that's not fully standardized yet.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick reply. So do you think, that without the Silverlight this scenario is not possible ? Is there a some kind of alternative, or am I left with "timer" solution only (every x seconds/minutes), then ?

Comment: Polling using JavaScript is the most common approach. You submit an AJAX request to your webservice, and use a javascript library such as jQuery to update the page in the user's browser, without having to do a full page refresh.

Comment: Yeah, sure that was my default option. I wanted something more sophisticated (efficient), but I guess this has to do. Now I'm glad I asked before exploring (or implementing even! :O) these other options. I totally forgot that the server wouldn't be able to use redirect :) I'll just use callback, I already have the infrastructure for callbacks working, so it will be easy enough. Thanks for saving me from a bitter disappointment, and some pointless work on my part.